# gprolog longest subset

Tags: prolog

I have list of integers, I need to find the longest subset of ascending integers from the list.
For example: `[1,2,5,3,6,7,4]` - longest subset would have been `SS = [1,2,3,6,7]`.

Can anyone show me at least the main guides to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

```
longestSubseq( List, Ans ) :-
    longestSubseq( List, [], [], Ans ).

longestSubseq( [], Buffer, [], Buffer ) :- !.

longestSubseq( [], _, AnsRevert, Ans ) :-
    reverse( AnsRevert, Ans ).

longestSubseq( [H | Tail], [], Longest, Ans ) :-
    longestSubseq( Tail, [H], Longest, Ans ).

longestSubseq( [H | Tail], [BufHead | BufTail], Longest, Ans ) :-
    BufHead =< H,
    longestSubseq( Tail, [H, BufHead | BufTail], Longest, Ans ).

longestSubseq( [H | Tail], Buffer, Longest, Ans ) :-
    [BufHead | _ ] = Buffer,
    BufHead > H,
    length( Longest, LongestLength ),
    length( Buffer, BufferLength ),
    ( 
        ( BufferLength > LongestLength, NewLongest = Buffer )
    ;
        ( BufferLength =< LongestLength, NewLongest = Longest ) 
    ),
    longestSubseq( Tail, [H], NewLongest, Ans ).
```

I not quite familiar with gprolog, so it's a swi-prolog code.

What we've got there is 2 predicates: `longestSubseq/2` and `longestSubseq/4`.

`longestSubseq/4` have a buffer (current monotonically subsequence), longest (longest subsequence at current time) and a accumulator Ans.

There are some behaviors what we need to handling in that accumulator:

1. Buffer is empty. We put new element in it.
2. New element is smaller than last buffer element. We put that element in buffer.
3. New element is larger than last buffer element. We clear buffer and put that element in it. If buffer was larger than longest subsequence, we substitute it.

So, it seems workable.

```
?- longestSubseq( [2], X ).
X = [2] ;
false.

?- longestSubseq( [2,1,2,3,2], X ).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Recurse passing the last seen element, to check ordering. Fail as soon as the passed element >= current head.

Answer (score 0):

A best-first search approach:

```
% not very tested!

longest(L, S) :-
        length(L, Len),
        advance(L, Len, [], [], S).

cmp_start([], _).
cmp_start([H|_], E) :- H =< E. 

add_to_bag([], P, [P]).
add_to_bag([H|T], P, Bag) :-
        P = LenP-_,
        H = LenH-_,
        (   LenH > LenP
        ->  Bag = [H|Bag1],
            add_to_bag(T, P, Bag1)
        ;   Bag = [P, H| T] ).

advance([Len-Start/Tail|Bag], Solution) :-
        advance(Tail, Len, Start, Bag, Solution).

advance([], _, Start, _, Solution) :-
        reverse(Start, Solution).

advance([H|Tail], Len, Start, Bag, Solution) :-
        Len1 is Len - 1,
        add_to_bag(Bag, Len1-Start/Tail, Bag1),
        (   cmp_start(Start, H)
        ->  advance(Tail, Len, [H|Start], Bag1, Solution)
        ;   advance(Bag1, Solution) ).
```

Partial solutions are represented as `MaximunLength-StartList/ListOfItemsToBeConsidered`.